# Whats the font family of that text?

Tags: font-design

Just wanted to know the font family of the `New Game` to download the ttf file

[image]

Can anyone please help out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This style is familiar from the Wild West. So, search Western fonts.

This especially resembles Carnivalee Freakshow:

[image]